# Trimmed swift video only saving untrimmed video Xcode 12 Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

Per [this tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/10857372-how-to-play-record-and-merge-videos-in-ios-and-swift) I have set up a simple "record" UIButton, where I am taken to the camera, can record video only, and after taking the video, am taken to the video editor screen where I can trim.  Once trimmed, I hit save and the video successfully saves to my camera roll.  However, it is only saving the untrimmed video.  (update below, with the UIVideoEditorController, I now get 2 unedited videos upon saving).

Code as follows:

VideoHelper.swift

```
import MobileCoreServices
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

enum VideoHelper {
  static func startMediaBrowser(
    delegate: UIViewController & UINavigationControllerDelegate & UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
    sourceType: UIImagePickerController.SourceType
  ) {
    guard UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType)
      else { return }

    let mediaUI = UIImagePickerController()
    mediaUI.sourceType = sourceType //checks to see if a movie exists on the camera roll, the camera itself, and the photo library
    mediaUI.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie as String] //allows only movies to be selected
    mediaUI.allowsEditing = true
    mediaUI.delegate = delegate
    delegate.present(mediaUI, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

RecordVideoViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices //contain predefined constants such as kUTTypeMovie which lets you select only video
import Photos
import AVFoundation

class RecordVideoViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBAction func record(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    VideoHelper.startMediaBrowser(delegate: self, sourceType: .camera) //opens the image picker and chooses the camera itself
    
  
  
  }
}
//MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
extension RecordVideoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  
    guard
      let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String,
      mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
      
      //1 gives you the URL pointing to the video
      let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL,
      
      //2 verify the app can save the file to the device's photo album
      UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path)
      else { return }
    
    //launches video editor
    guard UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath: url.path) else { return }
    
    let editor = UIVideoEditorController()
    
    editor.videoPath = url.path
    editor.videoMaximumDuration = 10.0
    editor.videoQuality = .typeIFrame1280x720
    
    present(editor, animated: true, completion: nil)
    
      
    //3 if it can, save it
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(
      url.path,
      self,
      #selector(video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)),
      nil)
    
    }
    //Displays an alert announcing whether the video file was saved or not, based on the error status
    @objc func video(
      _ videoPath: String,
      didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?,
      contextInfo info: AnyObject
    ) {
        
      let title = (error == nil) ? "Success" : "Error"
      let message = (error == nil) ? "Video was saved" : "Video failed to save"
        
      let alert = UIAlertController(
        title: title,
        message: message,
        preferredStyle: .alert)
      alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
        title: "OK",
        style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel,
        handler: nil))
      present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  
 
  
}
//MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate
extension RecordVideoViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
  
}

//MARK: - UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate
extension RecordVideoViewController: UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate {
  
}
```

I must be close as I have a successful video, it's just I only want the trimmed version.

**Update to RecordVideoViewController.swift**

I have now added the UIVideoEditorDelegate, and instantialized the delegate, as well as set the delegate and implemented the delegate methods. It now results in two saved videos, of which none are the edited one.

```
import UIKit
import MobileCoreServices //contain predefined constants such as kUTTypeMovie which lets you select only video
import Photos
import AVFoundation

class RecordVideoViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBAction func record(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    VideoHelper.startMediaBrowser(delegate: self, sourceType: .camera) //opens the image picker and chooses the camera itself
    
  
  
  }
}
//MARK: - UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
extension RecordVideoViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
  func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
  dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
  
    guard
      let mediaType = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaType] as? String,
      mediaType == (kUTTypeMovie as String),
      
      //1 gives you the URL pointing to the video
      let url = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.mediaURL] as? URL,
      
      //2 verify the app can save the file to the device's photo album
      UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(url.path),
    
     //****2.5?  Totally of the rails fromt he tutorial on this one:*****
      UIVideoEditorController.canEditVideo(atPath:url.path)
      else { return }
    
  
  
    //Must instantiate the UIVideoEditorController with "let editor = UIVideoEditorController()" and set the instance's delegate via self as well as show the file path

      let editor = UIVideoEditorController()
      editor.delegate = self

      editor.videoPath = url.path
  
      //presents the UIVideoEditorController
      self.present(editor, animated: true)
      print(editor.modalPresentationStyle.rawValue)
}
      // The UIVideoController's interface on the phone shows cancel and save buttons, which "do not" dismiss the presented view.  Must do that in the implementation of the delegate methods, of which there are 3.  And all 3 methods must be told to dismiss the presented view.
      // Delegate Method #1 (didSaveEditedVideoToPath): Called when the system has finished saving an edited movie.  At this point, the the trimmed video has already been saved to a file in app's temporary directory
  func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, didSaveEditedVideoToPath path: String) {
  self.dismiss(animated:true)
  
}
  

  //Delegate Method #2 (videoEditorControllerDidCancel): Called when the user has cancelled a movie editing operation
  func videoEditorControllerDidCancel(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController) {
  self.dismiss(animated:true)
}

  //Delegate Method #3 (didFailWithError): Called when the video editor is unable to load or save a movie.  Important as things "can" fail at this point.  MMhmmm
  func videoEditorController(_ editor: UIVideoEditorController, didFailWithError error: Error) {
  self.dismiss(animated:true)

    
    //***back on the rails with the tutorial, hope this works***
    
  //3 if it can, save it
  UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(
    editor.videoPath,
    self,
    #selector(video(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)),
    nil)
    
    }
  //Displays an alert announcing whether the video file was saved or not, based on the error status
  @objc func video(
    _ videoPath: String,
    didFinishSavingWithError error: Error?,
    contextInfo info: AnyObject
    ) {
        
    let title = (error == nil) ? "Success" : "Error"
    let message = (error == nil) ? "Video was saved" : "Video failed to save"
        
    let alert = UIAlertController(
      title: title,
      message: message,
      preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(
      title: "OK",
      style: UIAlertAction.Style.cancel,
      handler: nil))
    present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
  
 
  
}
//MARK: - UINavigationControllerDelegate
extension RecordVideoViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
  
}

//MARK: - UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate
extension RecordVideoViewController: UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate {
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code in iOS does not magically "wait" for something to happen. So, when you say this:

```
let editor = UIVideoEditorController()
// ...
present(editor, animated: true, completion: nil)
UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(
```

...you present the editor, but instead of waiting for the user to see the editor and do the trim, you *immediately* just go on to save the video as you originally have it.

So how *do* you wait? Well, look at the [UIVideoEditorController docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivideoeditorcontroller). It has a [*delegate*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivideoeditorcontroller/1622341-delegate). You must *set* that delegate (you cannot use a video editor controller without one), and you must implement the [delegate method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uivideoeditorcontrollerdelegate/1622336-videoeditorcontroller) in your delegate. As a result that method will be *called* — after the user edits! And when it is called it is handed the edited video! So *that* is where you proceed to save.

Comment: For actual example code that you can download and run, see my book example: https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/blob/66e806a9e05e7886cff64d4bd1b889104bae49fe/bk2ch15p660EmbeddedAVKit/EmbeddedAVKit/ViewController.swift This is a standard pattern in Cocoa programming, so learn the pattern and get used to it. You'll discover this sort of thing everywhere!

Comment: Thanks for this response.  I'm still very new and thought that having the extension RecordVideoViewController: UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate {
  
} would equivalent to "setting" it.  Going to read up more!

Comment: The fact that you declare RecordVideoViewController as a UIVideoEditorControllerDelegate is good. But that does not make it _the_ delegate of _the_ video editor controller. To do that, you would have to say `editor.delegate = self` — and you never said it. Nor did you implement the delegate _method_ that is called when the edit has finished, as I explained in my answer.

Comment: Your help is greatly appreciated.  I'm going to take a look at your detailed explanation and examples, and hope you don't mind if I follow up with a question if I hit a road block.

Comment: Hey Matt I spent a lot of time looking at your examples and think I have spent so much time looking at the screen I can't see if my changes make sense.  But I have added the delegate you mentioned and then dismissed it, then go for the save, and I do get a saved video, but the edits still don't show up.  I am thinking of starting from scratch but am I close in this current iteration?  Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like you’ve embedded one func inside another. Don’t do that. Look carefully at the layout in my example. Stay with it!

Comment: Hey matt, I had to upgrade my laptop battery and am back, and ready for more learning.  So I originally got the code (for learning purposes) from the tutorial at https://www.raywenderlich.com/10857372-how-to-play-record-and-merge-videos-in-ios-and-swift and wrote it out line for line.  After your suggestions, I looked at the UIVideoEditorController documentation and decided to build a sample project with your code to really wrap my head around things.  I took a random video on my computer and renamed it "ElMirage.mp4" just to make sure I didnt get fatal error unwrap.... (more in next comment)

Comment: ...I then added a UI button to the ViewController.swift file story board and left the name as the default "button".  I then used the assistant to link the "@IBAction func doEditorButton" to "button" (option and dragged to the UI button).  Then I ran it on my phone to see what happens.  I see the video on the top right of my phone and can click it and have options to fit the screen or rewind etc.  But I don't see the "button" that will allow me to test the edit feature.  Is the video "covering it" (even though the video appears as more a thumbnail in the top right until I click it).  Thanks!

Comment: Use the View Debugger to answer that question. It will show you what happened to the button.

Comment: So it looks like the screen is scaled where, if the button was in the middle of my storyboard screen, it was off the iphone's screen.  I manually moved it until I could see it.  I click the button and the edit screen appears but saving results in:  "saving to photos album
called
2020-10-22 15:35:15.389729-0600 Camera Test 2[1204:70859] [access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: Yup, so you will have to do that. You will see that I've done it in my tutorial example. — Good luck! We've now gone way beyond the scope of the original question, and it is not right for us to keep on like this.

Comment: Your help has been greatly appreciated.  Is the sample code the tutorial you are referring to?  Or is the tutorial in the book?

Comment: Yes, my sample code that you are talking about has the NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription.

Comment: Hello everyone, thanks to matt I was able to set the delegate as well as implement the 3 delegate methods necessary for use with UIVideoEditorController delegate, however there is one error that I have received when trying to set the delegate.  If anyone has any ideas, why setting the delegate would not work in this case, will be helpful to those who find this thread in the future.

Comment: Sigh. So the problem is that starting at `let editor = UIVideoEditorController()` your code is just sitting there outside of any method. The method `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` ended on the previous line when you closed it off with the curly brace. Swift code is not permitted to float in the middle of nowhere like that; everything must be inside some function. Now please, take it elsewhere! Ask a new question if you still have questions. What you are doing is called "leeching" and is considered rude on Stack Overflow.